# Spherically Wrapped Gaussian Distribution in NetLogo

Tags: math, statistics, netlogo, agent

I wish to rotate a vector in netlogo by an angle taken from a Gaussian Distribution.Using the code below:

```
to-report rotate-vector [ vec angle ]
  let x first vec
  let y last vec
  let mag sqrt (x * x + y * y)
  let old-angle atan x y
  let new-angle angle + old-angle
  report (list (mag * sin new-angle) (mag * cos new-angle))
end
```

For simulating extraction of angle from normal distribution I use the below:

```
set angle random-normal 0 <s.d>
```

But I am sure not that the implementation is correct in accordance with a spherically wrapped Gaussian distribution with standard deviation as mentioned in the paper http://www.princeton.edu/~icouzin/Couzin%20et%20al%20JTB.pdf (On page 3(column 2,3rd para) and On page 4 Table 1(error(s.d))).

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this paper is helpful to you: https://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/~wenzel/files/vmf.pdf (see sections 3 and 3.1).

Comment: A.B., I don't think you've asked this question in a way that's appropriate to StackOverflow. You're asking us to go and read through mathematical formulas elsewhere and check every line of your source code. The right way to do it would be to post the formulas here and specify exactly what you're unsure about (what lines, and why?). However, I wonder whether this would be a better question for Math.StackExchange.com (or stats.stackexchange.com?).  You can't expect people there to know NetLogo, but your code is easy to convert to generic pseudo-code that anyone who can program can understand.

Comment: You might want to use the NetLogo matrix extension.  There's a link to the documentation for it in the NetLogo use manual on the left under "Extensions".

Comment: BTW, to include math there, you can either paste an image of from the article, or use [this tool](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).  On Math.SE, you can use LaTeX markup as well.